# How can I place a column after another column for 1000 files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, text-processing, for

I have 1000 odt files:

- `file 1.odt` with 6 columns  (x,y,z,mx1,my1,mz1)
- `file 2.odt` with another 6 columns (x,y,z,mx2,my2,mz2)
- ....
- `file 1000.odt` with 5 columns (x,y,z,mx1000,my1000,mz1000)

How can put all in only 1 file namely "final.odt" with 1000 columns (mx1,mx2,mx3.....mx1000)? All files have the same number of rows and columns. Please, I am new in Cygwin64 Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the fourth column with `cut` from `file 1.odt` and append the other columns using a loop and `paste` using a temporary file:

```
cut -d, -f4 "file 1.odt" > final.odt
for i in {2..1000}; do
  paste -d, final.odt <(cut -d, -f4 "file ${i}.odt") > temp && mv temp final.odt
done
```